# Google Sheets / Excel - Change value based on other cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Quite a newbie when it comes to more advanced spreadsheet formulas. I am effectively trying to achieve the following on a finance spreadsheet.

I have multiple "accounts" with different values.

I have a sheet for money in and money out.

If account A has been selected in the previous cell, and then a value is added to either the money in or money out columns, I would like the value of the account to reduce or increase.

Hopefully this is enough info! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIF. Take a look at this example:

[image]

By choosing the entire columns E and F, now whenever you add something below the transaction data, the balance will be automatically updated.
The arguments in SUMIF function are `range`, `criteria` and `[sum_range]` respectively. So in this one, we are summing the values of column `F`, where the corresponding value in column `E` is equal to A (which is placed in cell `A2`).

You can also use Excel Tables as a neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in E3 and copy down.

```
=SUM(E2,C3,-D3)
```

E2, in this case, contains text (the column caption) which the SUM() function evaluates to 0. To this, the formula adds the amount in the *Money In* column and deducts whatever is in the *Money Out* column. One of these values will usually be zero but the total calculated by the formula will be the current balance.

[image]